# Is it possible to create variables in foreach using the $key?

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; // let say cars
}
```

Is it possible to create a new variable called `$cars`

Comment: You can create a new variable named "$cars". Now, please edit your post and explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: per the question, `$cars = "cars";`. Really need to clarify what you mean though.

Comment: Simply pass the $data to the view from the controller, but i must call it like $data['cars']. And to be more simple I want it to be $cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), like so:

```
$key = 'cars';
$$key = 'honda'; //$cars variable is created
echo $cars; //prints 'honda'
```

Comment: isn't this just the same as saying `$cars = 'honda';`?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn In my example yes, but I'm just illustrating the concept, when you receive 'honda' dynamically from an array like in OP's example you see its real usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)?

```
$data = array('thing' => 'ocean'
              'size' => 'big'
              'color' => 'blue');

extract($data);

echo "The $thing is $size and $color.";
```

[Prints:](http://codepad.org/m3Frn2nz)

> The ocean is big and blue.

---

You *can* use `foreach` and [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to do this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $$key = $value;
}
```

But this doesn't offer the simplicity or the options of `extract()` (eg: with `extract()`, you can add a prefix, control how you want to deal with collisions, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

yes: with `$key` containing `"cars"`, `echo $$key` would be the same as `echo $cars`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if it's possible to create a new variable that has the same name as the value of `$key` - so `'cars'` would create `$cars`, `'bikes'` would create `$bikes`, etc?

Yes, this is possible, although it's generally not the best way to get things done.

```
$data = array(
    'cars' => 7,
    'bikes' => 3
);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}

echo $cars; // 7
echo $bikes; // 3
```

Comment: @downvoter can you at least add a comment why ?

Answer (score -1):

the $key and $value variables don't have to be called $key and $value. You can rename the variables whatever you want (well any valid variable name).

```
foreach($data as $cars=>$model){
    echo "$cars => $model";
}
```